# Delphi7 Base64 encode UTF8 XML

Tags: delphi, utf-8, base64, delphi-7, encode

I'm still using Delphi7 (I know) and I need to encode an UTF8 XML in Base64 format.

I create the XML using IXMLDocument, which support UTF8 (that is, if I save to a file).

Since I'm using Indy10 to HTTP Post the XML request, I tried using TIdEncoderMIME to Base64 encode the XML. But some UTF8 chars are not encoded well.

Try1:

```
XMLText := XML.XML.Text;
EncodedXML := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(ToBytes(XMLText));
```

In the above case most probably some UTF8 information/characters are already lost when the XML is saved to a string.

Try2:

```
XMLStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
XML.SaveToStream(XMLStream);
EncodedXML := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(XMLStream);
//or
EncodedXML := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(XMLStream, XMLStream.Size);
```

Both of the above gives back EncodedXML = '' (empty string).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString()` method instead. It has an `AByteEncoding` parameter that you can use to specify the desired byte encoding that Indy should encode the string characters as, such as UTF-8, before it then base64 encodes the resulting bytes:

```
XMLText := XML.XML.Text;
EncodedXML := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(XMLText, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

Also note that in Delphi 2007 and earlier, where `string` is `AnsiString`, there is also an optional `ASrcEncoding` that you can use the specify the encoding of the `AnsiString` (for instance, if it is already UTF-8), so that it can be decoded to Unicode properly before then being encoded to the specified byte encoding (or, in the case where the two encodings are the same, the `AnsiString` can be base64 encoded as-is):

```
XMLText := XML.XML.Text;
EncodedXML := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(XMLText, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

You are getting data loss when using `EncodeBytes()` because you are using `ToBytes()` without specifying any encoding parameters for it.  `ToBytes()` has similar `AByteEncoding` and `ASrcEncoding` parameters.

In the case where you tried to encode a `TMemoryStream`, you simply forgot to reset the stream's `Position` back to 0 after calling `SaveToStream()`, so there was nothing for `EncodeStream()` to encode. That is why it returned a blank base64 string:

```
XMLStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  XML.SaveToStream(XMLStream);
  XMLStream.Position := 0; // <-- add this
  EncodedXML := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(XMLStream);
finally
  XMLStream.Free;
end;
```